# HTML attribute on anchor tag which executes Javascript when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, tags, onload

Is there an attribute I can give to an **anchor tag** in which I can put Javascript code that runs when the page is loaded.

Something like this:

```
 <a href="#" whenpageloads="alert('page loaded')" />blah blah</a>
```

It has to be added to an anchor tag, not the body tag of the page.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want functions to run on page load, there is onload in body tag.

```
<body onload="alert('page loaded')">
```

Comment: You could also use `onload` on the individual `a` element which would be called when that element is added to the DOM.  Could be useful for scoping or future flexibility in DOM loading, but start with the `body` version already suggested.

Comment: It has to be added to an anchor tag, but the "onload" attribute on the anchor tag doesn't run when the page is loaded somehow...

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to alert when an anchor tag loads, is the tag controlled by JavaScript?

Comment: Actually, @RikdeVos, the `onload` attribute is only supported by a limited number of HTML tags and the anchor tag is not one of them.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

You could do this on the `<body>` tag:

```
<body onload="alert('page loaded')">
    ...
</body>
```

The anchor tag has an `onclick` event which is trigerred when the anchor is clicked. But if you want to execute some javascript when the target page is loaded then you need to modify this target page and subscribe to the `onload` event on the `<body>` tag. Or do it unobtrusively:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        alert('page loaded');
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, that is not possible.

You could use the `onload` atrribute of the `BODY` tag or you could use jquery for the matter.

Comment: yeah, that was unfortunately what I was thinking... the onload attribute only seems to be working on the body tag, not anchor tags

Answer (score 0):

The answered posted are correct but I wonder if you're familiar with jquery for java script..? The document. Ready handler executes when the DOM has loaded and is ready

http://api.jquery.com/ready/